# Each function jquery with multiple divs

Tags: jquery

I have several divs with a class '.intro'. Within these divs I have button tags to trigger slide up and down of divs with class '.more'. How do I code it so that it opens the relevant 'more' div and not all of them at once?

This is the jquery I have tried so far:

```
function answer() {
   $(".trigger").click(function () {
        if ($(".slider").hasClass("slideup"))
            $(".slider").removeClass("slideup").addClass("slidedown");
         else
            $(".slider").removeClass("slidedown").addClass("slideup");
        });
   }; 



$.each($(answer($('.intro'))));
```

My HTML is here:

```
 <div class="container">
      <div class="icon">
        <img src="images/tour-1.png" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="intro">
      <button class="trigger">x</button>
      <h2>The gold standard</h2>
      <h3>Over 25 years training elite digital and direct marketers</h3>
      <div class="slider" class="slideup">
                <div class="more">
                   <p>Respected across the globe, we've awarded over 10,000 professional qualifications and trained 62,000 marketers on short courses. All IDM  digital marketing course content is continually reviewed and updated by a dedicated network of over 200 marketing practitioners.</p>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="icon">
        <img src="images/tour-6.png" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="intro">
      <button class="trigger">x</button>
      <h2>Professional marketing qualifications for digital marketers</h2>
      <h3>The IDM is the UK's only government approved awarding body for direct and digital marketing</h3>
      <div class="slider" class="slideup">
                <div class="more">
                   <p>Choose from our range of digital marketing courses, depending on your level and field of interest. Independent proof of your expertise and               commitment.</p>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="icon">
        <img src="images/tour-5.png" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="intro">
      <button class="trigger">x</button>
      <h2>Learn through technology</h2>
      <h3>Interactive and engaging content in the palm of your hand</h3>
      <div class="slider" class="slideup">
                <div class="more">
                   <p>We're passionate about bringing together the latest learning technology and expert digital marketing knowledge in a virtual campus full of               learning resources</p>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/4xym8evp/

Comment: Thanks Isherwood- I have added the CSS to the jsfiddle. I need help to write the each function for each 'intro' div. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Then you'll need to update the fiddle and the link here.

Comment: Is this what you're after http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rbs1nre1/?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4xym8evp/1/

Comment: Have a good read: [Tree Traversal | jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/)

Comment: Thanks MelanciaUK- I will read that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/4xym8evp/2/

```
$('.trigger').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.slider').find('.more').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Yes, that is a much simpler solution. Thank you Isherwood!

Answer (score 0):

If i understood, you want to slide up/down the div with class '.more' inside the div '.intro' which has the button triggered.

```
$(".trigger").click(function () {
    var slider = $(this).parent().find('.slider');
    if (slider.hasClass("slideup"))
        slider.removeClass("slideup").addClass("slidedown");
     else
        slider.removeClass("slidedown").addClass("slideup");
    });
};
```

Comment: Callebe, thanks but I have accepted the answer above. Check out the fiddle to make more sense of the question...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".trigger").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings(".slider").find(".more").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/60udf5q5/)